# How can I press each button to output the respective buttons time

Tags: swift, if-statement

So I connected my three buttons to one `IBAction` and wanted to know how I can press on each button, soft, medium, hard to output the number they are assigned, 5, 7, 12?

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let SoftTime = 5
    let mediumTime = 7
    let hardTime = 12


    @IBAction func hardnessSelected( hardnessSelected: Int) {

        let hardness = sender.currentTitle
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create new func like that (you can change the name) and link all your buttons

```swift
@IBAction func Buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.currentTitle {
        case "Soft":
            print("Soft button")
        case "medium":
            print("medium button")
        case "hard":
            print("hard button")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```